# ToggleButton group in complex layout

Tags: android

Supposed that I have a view structure like this:

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <ToggleButton />
        <ToggleButton />
        <ToggleButton />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <ToggleButton />
        <ToggleButton />
        <ToggleButton />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

My goal is to make toggle buttons act as group of radio button. There were a lots of answer on SOF saying that using `RadioGroup`. I tried some, they work but not as expected since they break TableRow's formats, say: column fixed width. Then I decided to use a recursive method to check & reset toggle button state as of below:

```
private void resetChildState(ViewGroup parent, int target) {
    int count = parent.getChildCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof TableRow) {
            resetChildState((ViewGroup)child, target);
        } else if (child instanceof ToggleButton) {
            if ((int)child.getTag() != target) {
                ((ToggleButton) child).setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but another problem came. The respond time is too bad since there were too much work on main thread which resulted in some laggy behaviors.

My question is: is there any other better approach for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of just the ToggleButtons and iterate over that to reset them.  Then you won't need to iterate over the entire view hierarchy.